# forEach is not a function when trying to loop through Firebase result set:

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to port some of my Firebase database calls to an IOT board that does not have jQuery, just good old JavaScript.

In my code I originally had a jQuery `$.each(tripData, function(index, element)` 
 ... loop to iterate through my results.

I have switched this to:

```
var tripsRef;
tripsRef = firebase.database().ref('trips/');
tripsRef.orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(100).on('value', function (response) {
var tripData = response.val();
tripData.forEach(function (index, element) {
    if (element.status >= 0) {
        var trip = new Object();
        trip.id = index;
        trip.launch = element.launch;
        trip.status = element.status;
    }
});
```

... but, I am getting the following error:

> forEach is not a function

I am not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for(let index in tripData){
  element = trimpData[index];
}
```

not realy foreach, but works exactly like it

but you also can use map functions

Answer (score 4):

You should really figure out if your response is an Array or Object.
`$.each()` iterates over arrays AND objects, thats why it works.

you should use `for...in` statement if you really want to iterate over this object `tripData`.

```
for(let prop in tripData)
{ 
   if (tripData.hasOwnProperty(index))
   { 
     item = tripData[prop];
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

lear about `for...in` statement here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 2):

While the answer by @TypedSource will iterate over the resulting children, the order in which it iterates is undetermined - and very likely not going to be by timestamp.

A snapshot that you get as the result for a query contains three pieces of information for each child: its key, its value, *and* its position relative to the other children. When you call `.val()` on the snapshot, you lose the relative ordering.

To maintain the order, use the built-in `forEach()` method of the snapshot:

```
var tripsRef;
tripsRef = firebase.database().ref('trips/');
tripsRef.orderByChild('timestamp').limitToLast(100).on('value', function (response) {
  var index = 0;
  response.forEach(function (child) {
    var element = child.val();
    if (element.status >= 0) {
      var trip = new Object();
      trip.id = index;
      trip.launch = element.launch;
      trip.status = element.status;
    }
    index++;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.of(response.val()).forEach` should work if it is just an array-like object missing its iterator

Comment: are you sure? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of

Comment: more or less, yeah: `function a() {
 Array.of(arguments).forEach(a => console.log(a))
}
undefined
a(1,23,4)
VM2663:2 [1, 23, 4, callee: function, Symbol(Symbol.iterator): function]`

Comment: this will generate an array with ONE entry `arguments ` NOT an array arguments. paste your code in console.. it only prints one entry and that emntry is an array-like object.

Comment: nope. see the output in the block I posted with my first comment. that's from the console. There is an array with each entry in the `arguments` as a separate place in the array.

Comment: then why do you get the same thing if you do this: `function a() { console.log(arguments) }` and then `a(1,23,4)` :)

Comment: because arguments is in fact an array just like the output, except it is missing its iterator. try `function a() {
 arguments.forEach(a => console.log(a))
}
;
a(1,23,4)` to see the difference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140203/discussion-between-ahmed-musallam-and-roberto-tomas).